# Removing item from array without the splice function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 3 rows, let's say:

```
Fruits = ["Appple", "Banana", "Mango"]
```

And I would like to change the [1]nd entry with "Pear", so the result should be:

`["Apple, "Pear", "Mango"]`

What I first did in my code was removing [1] with the splice and then adding the "Pear" in value [1], but the problem was while 'splicing' "Banana", the "Mango" took it's place, and afterwards the "Pear" overwrote the "Banana".
So the end result was:

```
["Apple", "Pear"]
```

instead of

```
["Apple", "Pear", "Mango"]
```

To solve this problem atm I did `Fruits[1] = 0;` but I don't know if this is a "secure" way for clearing an array ?
The values in the array are (fortunately) more complex than my example, some values (in the particular row) are changed / update so I prefer to "clear" them instead of just overwriting it.

Comment: you could assign the new value to the index of the array, without splicing. why does it not work for you?

Comment: just overwrite it dude

Comment: What the others said, you can just do Fruits[1] = "Pear"

Comment: My array is more complex than this ;)
It's a multi-dimensional array, where (when I add the new value) not all the values are "correct", I add / change afterwards new data into the particular row.

Comment: Just assign new value - Fruits[1] = "Pear" . And yes it is totally safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in simply way:

```js
var fruits = ["Appple", "Banana", "Mango"];
fruits[1]="Peer";
console.log(fruits);
```

Or using `splice` method.

> The `splice()` method adds/removes items to/from an array.

This is the syntax : **array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)**

- **index**  -> An integer that specifies at what position to add/remove items(**required**).
- **howmany**  -> The number of items to be removed. If set to 0, no items will be removed.(**optional**)
- **item1, ..., itemX**  -> The new item(s) to be added to the array (**optional**)

```js
var fruits = ["Appple", "Banana", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(1,1,"Peer"); //remove "Banana" item and add "Peer" item
console.log(fruits);
```

If you have an `array` of `objects`.

```
var fruits = [["Appple","red","20g",4],["Banana","yellow","10g",3], ["Mango","green","123g",5]];
fruits.splice(1,1,["Pear", "green", "50gr", 4]);
console.log(fruits);
```

Or simply:

```
fruits[1]=["Pear", "green", "50gr", 4];
```

Comment: Can you add with the splice function (the one on row 3 in your 2nd example) a more complex object than just a string ? In my example I have a multi-dimensional array, so instead of "Pear" I would like to add something like ["Pear", "green", "50gr", 4] etc.

Comment: @smirnoff103, yes, it is possible. Look at my answer. I update it.

Comment: Thanks this might be my answer to my question (your mango's are pretty heavy though ;) )

Comment: Hmm I don't know if the very last `fruits[1]=["Pear", "green", "50gr", 4];` can be used. Because I did later something like `fruits[1][4] = "rotten"`, what would happen to this value in on the [4]th level when I do `fruits[1]=["Pear", "green", "50gr", 4];` ?

Comment: The item will have only 4 fields

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna replace just the value of the array, where the value is apple (And you don't know which index) just use something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.Length; i++)
{
    if(fruits[i] == 'Apple')
    {
        fruits[i] = 'Peer';
    }
}
else { continue; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Splice has a method to remove and add new elements. This script will do what you want:

```
var fruits = ["Appple", "Banana", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(1, 1, 'Pear');
console.log(fruits);
```

Here, you are saying that splice 1 items at index 1 and push "Pear" in that index.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this below code, this will remove "Banana" in array without using splice method,

```js
var fruits = ["Appple", "Banana", "Mango"];
fruits[1]="";
console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: That just sets it to the empty string